# Generate a call for R_GetCCallable through Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

Suppose I’m building an R package with C files that call C code from other R packages through `R_GetCCallable`, e.g.

```
void R_init_thispackage(DllInfo *info) {
    …
    zoo_lag      = (SEXP(*)(SEXP,SEXP,SEXP)) R_GetCCallable("zoo","zoo_lag");
}
```

new_cfile.c

```
SEXP new_func (SEXP arg1, SEXP arg2, SEXP arg3)
{
    SEXP temp = zoo_lag(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    ...
}
```

And I want to call these C files (from the package being built) in C++ through `Rcpp`:

When `Rcpp` generates the file `src/RcppExports.cpp`, it automatically adds there the function for package initialization (something like `R_init_thispackage`). Since I need to add an extra line inside the function for the import from another package, I’m wondering if there is some way to tell `Rcpp` to include that import, e.g. through some keyword, so that it would not need to be added manually after each re-generation.

Comment: Sections 2.4 or 2.5 in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you by chance confusing exporting and importing?  The [RcppXTS](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppxts) package does what you seem to be interested in: access `zoo` and `xts` code.  But the `R_GetCCallable()` code is in the header [xtsAPI.h](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/blob/master/inst/include/xtsAPI.h) ie in the _exporting_ package and not in the importing one.

Comment: I think @RalfStubner is right -- you want to look at Section 2.4 in that vignette

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The snippet `// [[Rcpp::init]]` did the trick. Although, I now realize that `R_GetCCallable()` can go anywhere in the code and not necessarily in the init function.